# Como utilizar o valor de um campo HTML dentro do code behind C#?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Tenho um código JavaScript que faz a criação de campos HTML em uma página Asp.net. Como faz para chamar a função para o *Code Behind* e retornar para os campos criados? Se eu pudesse usar ASP.NET nesse caso, teria que criar vários `Textbox` e manipular o valor no servidor.

```
<input type="text" onblur="pesquisa(this.name, 1)" maxlength="10" size="10" value="" name="contrato1" onkeypress="FiltraTecla(event);">
```

Comment: Já pensou em usar jQuery+Ajax?

Comment: Na realidade para pegar o conteúdo eu devo dar um request dentro da página, mas o meu problema é como eu chamar a função pesquisa que esta dentro do codebehide

Comment: Justamente, com Ajax você deve atingir o seu objetivo. (:

Comment: Você poderia postar um exemplo?

Comment: O que exatamente você precisa criar?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Já criei via javascript uma série de inputs textbox. Preciso recuperar a informação digitada dentro do codebehide e depois retornar o resultado para o restante dos componentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informe um `name` para o elemento, e então no code-behind utilize `Request.Form["nomeDoElemento"]` para obtê-lo.

Por exemplo, caso o código JavaScript crie um elemento

```
<input type="text" name="nomeDoCliente" />
```

o valor deste campo pode ser obtido no code-behind da seguinte forma:

```
string cliente = Request.Form["nomeDoCliente"];
```

Comment: Deu certo, agora o problema é que o meu input type='textbox' não estar alterando o valor quando sai do javascript.

Comment: O input deveria ser alterado para algum valor específico?